# What is the simplest way of extracting the depth values of the scene?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, depth-of-field

I am totally new in the 3D-world, But I am really interested in having the depth values of the scene 
(in the raw floating point numbers format),

Unfortunately, I could not find an associated question (and also its answers) in the whole **Blender beta** society about that,

Any possible help is highly appreciated in advance, Thanks a lot.

Comment: The term you are looking for is called Z-Depth: the distance from the camera to your object in blender units. More info here: https://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/input/render_layers.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood the request.
In case you intend to as depth values: values of the z-buffer of the camera
then the answer is easy.

you have to use this simple code:

```
#first import the libraries
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

context = bpy.context
scene = bpy.context.scene   

#create the def for take the z-buffer
def checkCameraView(cam, obj):
    for v in obj.data.vertices:
        x, y, z = world_to_camera_view(context.scene, cam, obj.matrix_world * v.co)
        print(z)

#select the camera
cam = scene.camera
#check every mesh type objects in the scene
for obj in scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH' :
        checkCameraView(cam, obj)
```

z is the depth of the vertex
x and y are the coordinates on the Cartesian coordinate plane (2D) of the chamber
x = horizontal
y = vertical

api link: [world_to_camera_view](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy_extras.object_utils.html?highlight=world_to_camera_view#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view)

This was the question?

Comment: #Odino Thanks for your attention.Yes, that was my question, but when I want to run the script, I receive a "script fail" message (probably related to the last line). Should I modify anything in the code to run it correctly?

Comment: @Ali It was only part of a possible script.
now is complete ;)
P.S. It is a simple script that you can use as an example

Comment: Thank you very much, It works! Just one point. It seems that I have to run Blender from the Linux Terminal to see the results. I'll find a way to write them into a file. That should not be difficult! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your talking about the Z pass. It's activated by default but shows only white because the values are greater than 1 (0 is black, 1 is white, more than 1 is white). There's nothing to see unless you use a normalize node to make the values 0 to 1.

[image: Z-Pass]

Comment: #Bithur Thanks, but in this situation, how can I save the generated depth values in blender units? Should I use another node to do so?

Comment: The Z pass gives the distance of each pixel to the camera in blender units. You can save it as a B&W image from the render (Change "combined" to "Depth" pass and save as image) or with a file output node in compositor.

Comment: If you are going to save the Z pass as image, make sure you save it in a format that can take values larger thatn one like OpenEXR